# Create URL template variable in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have the following PHP to create a list of categories in Smarty.

```
$result_categories = $con->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE u_id='$blog_user[id]'");
$list_categories=array();
while ($row_categories = $result_categories->fetch_assoc())
{
$list_categories[]=$row_categories;
}
```

I want to make a template variable to get the proper link of a category. For example `http://domain.com/username/category.php?id=*CAT_ID*` as `{$Variable}` or `{$row_categories.variable}` (after what`s most appropriate)

How can i manage this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can try the following:

```
while ($row_categories = $result_categories->fetch_assoc())
{
$list_categories[]=$row_categories;
$info_smarty->assign('variable',$list_categories); //or however you assign your variables
}
```

And in your smarty template you can call only 1 link:

```
{$variable[0]}
```

Or every link:

```
{foreach item=links from=$variable} 
{$links}
{/foreach}
```